# CodeIgniter is generating too many sessions file at server tmp folder

Tags: php, codeigniter

I don't know why but my CodeIgniter application is creating too many ci_sessions file at server tmp folder. like 1000 session file ever min. and seems not deleting old session file

I am using this settings

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 1000;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = TRUE;
```

How to get rid this issue ?

[image]

Comment: which CI and Php version are you using?

Comment: PHP Version 7.1.27 , 
CI VERSION :  '3.0.4'

Comment: if possible upgrade do CI 3.1.10, there have been some bugs in the session library resolved: see here https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/changelog.html

Comment: @Vickel right now added session.gc_probability = 1  and now no session files.

Answer (score 3):

In your php.ini add this

```
session.gc_probability = 1
session.gc_divisor = 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
```

Also in your codeigniter configuration file check that you have enabled the regenerate_destroy and expiration enabled.

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = ‘mysession';
$config['sess_expiration'] = (60 * 60); 
$config['sess_save_path'] = FCPATH . "sessions";
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = TRUE;
```

Basically gc_probability is set by default in 0 and those files can't be deleted. So changed to 1 enable the file deletion automatically.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution*

Add this code

```
ini_set('session.save_path',realpath(dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) . '/tmp'));
ini_set('session.gc_probability', 1);
```

Answer (score -2):

I am facing same issue in my live server i have review many thing but after i have solved using cronjob.

Emergency approach to remove session file

1)

```
sudo find /var/lib/php/sessions/. -type f|wc -l
```

-this command give you count of your current session

2)

```
`cd /var/lib/php/sessions` and fire du -sh then it’s
```

Give size of you session file

But you have to go for

```
cd /var/lib/php/sessions you to become 

Root user for this you have to use sudo su

1)sudo su

2)cd /var/lib/php/sessions

3)du -sh
```

After fire below command for remove all session in projects

But please be aware if you remove the session folder so that time web site session is not working.

Follow step by step Command

```
1)sudo rm -rf /var/lib/php/sessions

   -remove session folder

2)

cd /var/lib/php

mkdir sessions


3)sudo chmod -R 1733 sessions/
```

This is useful when you have so many session files and because the server is full at that time you can clear the session's folder size.

**Remove all session with timeout and without time out**

1. sudo su
2. crontab -e
3. set cron using below

   05 05 * * * ionice -c 2 nice -n 19 find /var/lib/php/sessions -type f -cmin +4320 -exec sudo rm {} ;

his command run on 5:05 am and remove session file before 72hour (4320/60 = 72)

Some time so many session file so at that time not remove session file 24 hour so

At time some time override our cron for that i have suggest you can set timeout

In cron so after that time cron is automatically closed.

Please check this url we have write every step in it https://myphpinformation.blogspot.com/2024/01/codeigniter-generating-too-many-sessions-files-resolved-and-remove-session-in-cron-job.html